# How to extract Year and Month in SQL Postgres by using Data_Part function

Tags: postgresql, data-analysis

I am facing an issue extracting the month and year from the data (in Character varying type) >> InvoiceDate in SQL Postgres. I have seen the solution is relatively easy with MySQL function: DATEFROMPARTS as per the below Code which is not available in SQLpostgres.  How can I get the same result DATA_PART function in Postgres SQL, but simultaneously I need to change the data type of the column "InvoiceDate" to the date

```
Select
CustomerID,
min(InvoiceDate) first_purchase_date,
DATEFROMPARTS(year(min(InvoiceDate)), month(min(InvoiceDate)), 1) Cohort_Date
```

into #cohort
from #online_retail_main
group by CustomerID

The output:

```
Customer ID|  first_purchase_date    |Cohort_Date|
-----------+-------------------------+-----------+
   12345   | 2010-12-20 15:47:00:00  | 2010-12-01|
```

I am trying to make a date consits of Year and Month , while the day to be set as 1 for all

Comment: Where [in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions.html) did you find the functions `datefromparts()` `month()` or `year()`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name

I didn't find it in Postgres, it is only available with MySql, how can I do the same in Postgres?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name
I have looked at the documentation, but all the examples show that Date_part extracts only one value per code such a month, but the codes which I have posted showing DATEFROMPARTS function can get all (year,month , and day) from the column

Comment: Is the `timestamp` value really `2010-12-20 15:47:00:00`? This part `00:00` is invalid in Postgres is it valid in MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a valid Postgres `timestamp`:

```
select date_trunc('month', '2010-12-20 15:47:00.00'::timestamp)::date;

 date_trunc 
------------
 12/01/2010

--or ISO format

set datestyle = 'ISO,MDY';

select date_trunc('month', '2010-12-20 15:47:00.00'::timestamp)::date;

 date_trunc 
------------
 2010-12-01
```

Uses [date_trunc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to truncate the `timestamp` to a month which means the first of the month. Then cast(`::date`) to a `date` type. The `DateStyle` just deals with how the value is presented to the user. The value is not stored formatted.

To do something similar to what you did in MySQL:

```
select make_date(extract(year from '2010-12-20 15:47:00.00'::timestamp)::integer, extract(month from '2010-12-20 15:47:00.00'::timestamp)::integer, 1);
```

This uses `make_date` from here [Date/time functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html) and `extract` to build a `date`.

Comment: Your answer is very near to the solution, I applied your code :

select make_date(extract(year from MIN(InvoiceDate::timestamptz))::integer, extract(month from MIN(InvoiceDate::timestamptz))::integer, 1)

FROM l_main_online_retail


But I got this error :

[22008] ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "13/12/2010 9:02" Hint: Perhaps you need a different "date style" setting. 
How Can I fix this issue?

Comment: check my above comment please

Comment: Follow the instructions in the `Hint` section of the error message.  This `13/12/2010` is being seen as `MM/DD/YYYY` instead of `DD/MM/YYYY`. That is due to the setting for [DateStyle](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-INTERVAL-INPUT) *Table 8.15. Date Order Conventions*. Read that section and make appropriate change to setting.